# How can I connect GitLab to an external database using a kubernetes secret on values.yaml?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, yaml, amazon-rds, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to connect GitLab to an external database an AWS RDS using a k8s secret to deploy on AWS EKS but I am not sure if it connects and how would I know that it does?

values.yaml code:

```
psql:
  connectTimeout:
  keepalives:
  keepalivesIdle:
  keepalivesInterval:
  keepalivesCount:
  tcpUserTimeout:
  password: 
    useSecret: true
    secret: gitlab-secret
    key: key
  host: <RDS endpoint>
  port: <RDS port>
  username: postgres
  database: <main name of db>
  # applicationName:
  # preparedStatements: false
```

kubernetes secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic gitlab-secret --from-literal=key="<password>" -n devops-gitlab
```

The psql server details are already known